# How can I get microphone dB level in a script?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I would like to get microphone input level in spark ar script for an AR filter I'm developing.

- It looks like this existed at this link at some point but the page is empty now: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/tutorials-and-samples/audio-analyzer-and-energy-meter/
- I tried to create a bit crusher patch and connect its output to a value patch and pass that to script but spark ar shows an error: "Please check the patch graph and try again" 
  Also I have no idea what type that would be so I can't read it on the script.

Comment: Questions are free; if you have two questions then ask two questions. The second question seems unrelated to the title. If you make a new question for it, try to include a minimal example.

Comment: that is a potential way to answer my question so it's actually additional information for my original question. It might seem unrelated to you maybe because you don't know the question or the answer. thanks for the information you provided: TIL questions are free on SO.